# xrandr layout of virtual screen

Tags: linux, xrandr

Sometimes I need to use a virtual screen which is bigger than the physical one. With `xrandr` this is no problem.
If I need 2000x1500, I use this command:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --rate 60 --mode 1366x768 --fb 2000x1500 --panning 2000x1500
```

This gives me something like:

```
    0                       2000
   0 ------------------------
     | LVDS1  |             |
     |1366x768|             |
     |TTTTTTTT|             |
     |---------             |
     |                      |
     |     virtual screen   |
     |      2000x1500       |
1500 ------------------------
```

This is almost fine, but what I really want is:

```
    0                       2000
   0 ------------------------
     |                      |
     |     virtual screen   |
     |      2000x1500       |
     |---------             |
     | LVDS1  |             |
     |1366x768|             |
     |TTTTTTTT|             |
1500 ------------------------
```

I want to have the second layout because I use the taskbar of my KDE desktop environment, and I want the KDE taskbar to be on the bottom of the screen;
see the TTTTT line in both pictures.

(Actually the taskbar is almost in the middle of the screen.)

I thought the `--pos` option would help:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --rate 60 --mode 1366x768 --fb 2000x1500 --panning 2000x1500 --pos 0x732
```

but the result is still the layout shown first. Panning:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --rate 60 --mode 1366x768 --fb 2000x1500 --panning 2000x1500+0+732
```

also doesn't help.

How can I get this "layout" of my virtual screen?

Answer (score 0):

The trick with `--panning` is that it wants to follow your mouse cursor around.  So if you shift the mouse pointer to where you want it, the panning should follow.

Install the `xdotool` package, then try this:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --rate 60 --mode 1366x768 --fb 2000x1500 --panning 2000x1500
xdotool mousemove 0 1500
```

This will move the mouse cursor to the bottom left, and your window will follow.

`xdotool` also has a `getmouseposition` command that can be used to save your mouse position, so you can decide whether you want to move the mouse back to where it was afterwards.

Comment: Panning is exactly wat i want. Testing your suggestion with xdotool gives me the same result as without (like i showed in the first "picture"). I want to have the other layout, because i use the taskbar of my desktop environment. Actual the taskbar is almost in the middle of the screen, but i want it to be on the bottom.

Comment: Ah, I see -- you're looking to control where your taskbar is placed.  That could depend heavily on your taskbar software.  Edit your question to specifically mention the taskbar, and specify what taskbar program you use (or what desktop environment).

Comment: I'm using XFCE as desktop environment. Since i haven't changed there anything, it must be the default XFCE taskbar program.